# When to use rxjava2 extensions MulticastProcessor

Tags: rx-java, rx-java2

What is the purpose of `MulticastProcessor` from rxjava extensions? For example with one source and two sinks normal pattern is:

```
Flowable<T> f = ...
ConnectableFlowable<T> published = f.publish();
published.map(mapper1).subscribe(s1);
published.map(mapper2).subscribe(s2);
published.connect();
```

As far as I understand it, equivalent code with `MulticastProcessor` would be:

```
Flowable<T> f = ...
MulticastProcessor<T> mp = MulticastProcessor.create(true);
mp.map(mapper1).subscribe(s1);
mp.map(mapper2).subscribe(s1);
f.subscribe(mp);
```

Assuming that the two pieces of code are equivalent, when would one use one or the other. The javadoc of `MulticastProcessor` seems to be a bit too concise.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you read the relevant [guide entry](https://github.com/akarnokd/RxJava2Extensions#multicastprocessor)?

> Works similarly to `publish(Function)` and multicasts items to subscribers if all of them are ready to receive the items.
>   In addition, it supports a mode where the last subscriber cancelling will trigger a cancellation to the upstream.
>   If you need it to run without subscribing the `MulticastProcessor` to another `Publisher` use `start()` or `startUnbounded()`.
>   Use `offer()` to try and offer/emit items but don't fail if the internal buffer is full.

```java
MulticastProcessor<Integer> mp = Flowable.range(1, 10)
    .subscribeWith(MulticastProcessor.create());

mp.test().assertResult(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10);

// --------------------

MulticastProcessor<Integer> mp2 = MulticastProcessor.create(4);
mp2.start();

assertTrue(mp2.offer(1));
assertTrue(mp2.offer(2));
assertTrue(mp2.offer(3));
assertTrue(mp2.offer(4));

assertFalse(mp2.offer(5));

mp2.onComplete();

mp2.test().assertResult(1, 2, 3, 4);
```

The standard `PublishProcessor` is not equivalent to the `publish()` operator because the former doesn't coordinate downstream requests. In addition, some implementations of Reactive Streams and the TCK expects a processor to cancel its upstream when all downstream `Subscriber`s have unsubscribed, similar to how `refCount` works with an RxJava-specific `ConnectableFlowable`. `MulticastProcessor` can support this behavior as well.

Comment: What is meant by coordination of downstream requests? Maybe there is and example that can show the difference between the two in coordinating the requests.

Comment: That means if one subscriber requested 2 and another 3, they both get 2 elements and no next item until the first subscriber requests more. `publish()` and `MulticastProcessor` work the same, `PublishProcessor` requests unbounded and will fail a subscriber if it hasn't requested enough. Not sure why you need exampe of such internal behaviors. Apply `doOnRequest` and see the difference in the patterns.

Comment: Thanks, that is clear, no example is needed. It is more clear now, although the guide entry documentation seems a bit weird to me, as it describes `MulticastProcessor` but there is no actual multicasting going on in both of the examples. So could `Flowable.publish()` be implemented with `MulticastProcessor`?

Comment: It [is implemented](https://github.com/ReactiveX/RxJava/blob/2.x/src/main/java/io/reactivex/internal/operators/flowable/FlowablePublishMulticast.java#L58) with one and maybe it will be in [3.x](https://github.com/akarnokd/Reactive4JavaFlow/blob/master/src/main/java/hu/akarnokd/reactive4javaflow/impl/operators/ConnectableFolyamPublish.java#L49).